# Hot Reload Visual Studio 22 Shortcut

Tags: visual-studio-2022

Is there and if so what is the default keyboard shortcut for Hot Reload in Visual Studio 2022?

I have looked through the official page but am unable to find it here:
[Keyboard Shortcuts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/default-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022)

Answer (score 5):

It says ALT+F10 on my machine... check out your settings by searching for "keyboard" in the menubar's search, then look for "apply" in the options popup.

[image]